# RecyclerView like Instagram's videos you should like

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make an effect like the one of Instagram Videos you should like

[image]

Anyone knows how can i achieve that in horizontal direction?
I was trying with LinearSnapHelper to center the selected one, but couldn't change the "view"

Answer (score 2):

for Recyclerview

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

for better same like switching page one by one.. better use Viewpager

Comment: Yes, but i mean the effect of changing the layout of the "selected" view by the Snap Helper...